# Can ThreadLocal be used in Cucumber paralel tests using mvn surefire plugin

Tags: java, multithreading, cucumber, maven-surefire-plugin

In our e2e project we want to parallelise test scenarios execution. In few places we would like to have something stored per thread e.g. WebDriver, scenario specific state etc. My first approach would be to use ThreadLocal like:

```
private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driverHolder = new ThreadLocal<>();
```

But also keeping in mind issues using combination of ThreadLocal and thread pools (for example the ones mentioned here [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal#threadlocalsand-thread-pools)) I am wondering if ThreadLocal can actually be used in this context.

I don't know the insights of cucumber or surefire implementation details so I don't know if that kind of setup is thread safe as I am not fully controlling how these thread spawned and how teared down, which means that I can't clean up the ThreadLocal in an appropriate moment.

Comment: there is no "issue" with ThreadLocals and pools. When using pools - you just need to do the cleap-up manually and since this is only for tests, honestly, who cares if you do not clean them up promptly? When tests are done they will be destroyed and clean-up will happen _anyway_

Comment: I suggest to not use `hooks` while using `ThreadLocal`

Comment: @Eugene As fas as I understand the issue can occurs, when cucumber decides to reuse thread from the pool that was already used for different scenario. Then some thread related data can be associated with it.
But now I am thinking that if we clean all thread related data in one of cucumber hooks it should work properly.

Comment: @NandanA Any reason behind?

Answer (score 0):

I am using  [`courgette-jvm`](https://github.com/prashant-ramcharan/courgette-jvm) in conjunction with [`cucumber-guice`](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.cucumber/cucumber-guice/latest/io/cucumber/guice/package-summary.html) to parallelize tests without `ThreadLocal`. It  enters scenario specific info from gherkin into the ui and doesn't require any `ThreadLocal` or `pool` . Also it doesn't require you to clean anything. This setup automatically creates separate webdriver instances per scenario and runs separate browsers in parallel. I use it with selenium hub and extend it to docker if needed

```
import courgette.api.CourgetteOptions;
import courgette.api.CourgetteRunLevel;
import courgette.api.CucumberOptions;
import courgette.api.testng.TestNGCourgette;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
@CourgetteOptions(
        threads = 10,
        runLevel = CourgetteRunLevel.SCENARIO,
        rerunFailedScenarios = true,
        rerunAttempts = 1,
        showTestOutput = true,
        reportTitle = "Courgette-JVM Example",
        reportTargetDir = "build",
        environmentInfo = "browser=chrome; git_branch=master",
        cucumberOptions = @CucumberOptions(
                features = "src/test/resources/com/test/",
                glue = "com.test.stepdefs",
                //tags = {"@post or @get"},
                publish = true,
                plugin = {
                        "pretty",
                        "json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json",
                        "html:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.html"}
        ))
class AcceptanceIT extends TestNGCourgette {
}
```

relevant pom elements

```
</dependency>
      <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
      <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.1</version>
</dependency>
      <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.prashant-ramcharan</groupId>
    <artifactId>courgette-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>5.11.0</version>
</dependency>
      <dependency>
  <!-- httpclient dpendendecy is to resolve courgette-jvm error -  NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/TrustAllStrategy -->        
 <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.10</version>
</dependency>
```

RemoteWebdriver config

```
protected RemoteWebDriver createDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
       
        String hubURL = 
            "http://192.168.1.3:"+"selenium hub port here"+"/wd/hub";
             ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
             DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
             capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
             return (RemoteWebDriver) (driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL), capabilities));

        }

        @Override
         public RemoteWebDriver getDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
                this.createDriver();
                return (RemoteWebDriver) driver;
        }
```

cucumber-guice related configs

```
    import io.cucumber.guice.ScenarioScoped;    
    @ScenarioScoped
          public class Global {
          public RemoteWebDriver driver;
           
          public Global() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
                driver = new DriverFactory().getManager();
               // getManager() should have driver from above createDriver()

          }
    }
```

Inject `Global` class in your stepdefs like below (do necessary imports). You can inject helper classes also and guice will have it available per scenario

```
 @Inject
   Global global;
 
  //then you can do
   global.driver.get(site);
```

pom for cucumber-guice

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-guice</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's a valuable approach. However I don't think we are going to make such a change right now.